# Change Label Text Color when low Number

Tags: nsstring, uilabel

I am working on an test/demo app where users enter scores in UITextField and tap a UIButton to then display the sum of the scores in a UIText Label. I'd like the lowest score to either change the UILabel Color or Change the UILabel Text Color for the lowest number. This is so users can easily see who has the lowest score. Score calculation works fine after button is pressed, just would like to add this feature.

```
- (IBAction)calculateScore:(id)sender{

//Player 1

float p112=([_player1Text12.text floatValue]);
float p111=([_player1Text11.text floatValue]);
float p110=([_player1Text10.text floatValue]);
float p19=([_player1Text9.text floatValue]);
float p18=([_player1Text8.text floatValue]);
float p17=([_player1Text7.text floatValue]);
float p16=([_player1Text6.text floatValue]);
float p15=([_player1Text5.text floatValue]);
float p14=([_player1Text4.text floatValue]);
float p13=([_player1Text3.text floatValue]);
float p12=([_player1Text2.text floatValue]);
float p11=([_player1Text1.text floatValue]);
float p1total= p112+p111+p110+p19+p18+p17+p16+p15+p14+p13+p12+p11+([_player1Text0.text floatValue]);

_player1Score.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", p1total];
```

I know there are easier ways to do my calculations (in terms of the amount of code) and perhaps its not possible with the way I have things set up to do the highlighting of the high number.

Again, I'm just learning so this is all experimental for me and won't be published. I have a lot of learning/reading left to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Side note - consider using an array instead of twelve separate ivars.

Comment: Yeah I know an array is better for this. I'm still reading my book to figure out how to do it.